# What is the method signature means? String value() default "";

Tags: java, spring-boot, syntax, annotations

I came across this method signature in Spring Component interface.

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Indexed
public @interface Component 
{
   String value() default "";
}
```

What is the method signature `String value() default "";`  means? 
How and When should we define such syntax for our coding purposes?

Comment: It's straight forward. It's Spring component name. If user does not provide the name then default is "".   it is majorly used when you want to name the bean. E.g. Animal class has 2 instances so I cannot autowire them directly hence i need to name them and then autowire using named beans.

Comment: @SagarGandhi So if my understanding is correct, you are referring to use the Qualifier tag and then autowire the instance using the qualified name value. Like for example I have two instances Tiger and Lion and I use the Qualifier ("tiger") and ("Lion") at component level  and then I can autowire them by giving their qualified names like Lion and Tiger. Am i correct?

Comment: yes right. Basically, with that, you can give a name to an instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is no method signature. it means that you can pass a String as parameter to the Component annotation, like this:

```
@Component(value = "value")
```

If you don't specify a value your self, the default value "" will be used.

If it had been like this:

```
String value(); // without the default
```

value would have been a mandatory parameter. Trying to use Component like this:

```
@Component()
```

would lead to an Exception, since you didn't provide a value.

EDIT: when to use.

If you don't know much about this syntax, or annotations in general, you shouldn't use them. About everything that can be done using annotations, especially custom made ones, can also be done without annotations.

Let's say you want to create an annotation to validate the value of a field.
I'll be using the example of Belgian postal codes. They all are 4 digits, and are between 1000 and 9999.

```
@Target( {ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention( RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint( validatedBy = ValidatePostalCodeImpl.class)
public @interface ValidatePostalCode{
  String message() default "You have entered an invalid postal code";
  Class<?>[] groups() default {}; // needed for the validation
  Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default{}; // needed for the validation

  int maxValue() default 9999; // so, by default, this will validate based
  int minValue() default 1000; // on these values, but you will be able to 
  // override these
}
```

/* Validation implementation */

```
public class ValidatePostalCodeImpl implements ConstraintValidator<ValidatePostalCode, Integer> {

    int upperValue;
    int lowerValue;

    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidatePostalCode validate) {
        this.upperValue = validate.maxValue(); // here you call them as if they indeed were regular methods
        this.lowerValue = validate.minValue();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Integer integer, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return integer >= lowerValue && integer <= upperValue;
    }

}
```

/* Usage */

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "addresses")
public class Addresses {

  // home address -> In Belgium, so has to be between the default values:
  @ValidatePostalCode
  Integer belgianPostalCode;

  // vacation home in another country, let's say the PC's there are between
  // 12000 and 50000
  @ValidatePostalCode(minValue = 12000, maxValue = 50000)
  Integer foreignPostalCode;

}
```

Sure, this is a very limited example, but it should get you an idea.

Comment: Thank you @Stultuske for the answer. However my second question remains.. What is the scenario when I should use the above syntax in my coding? Can you please explain?

Comment: I'll add an example in my answer

Comment: It will be very helpful...Thank you very much for your time

Comment: Thank you @Stultuske for the example. I am 100% clear on the subject now. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

The `@interface` keyword is used to define an annotation. This annotation has a property called `value`, which you could specify explicitly:

```
@Component(value = "myValue")
```

Or in the shorthand form:

```
@Component("myValue")
```

If you don't specify the `value`, it will default to `""`, as defined by the `default` keyword.